# Axios Api calls in Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, axios

I've deployed my app to heroku and I have it connected to mongoLab. My problem is my API calls using axios wont't work with Heroku because they are still set up locally. Is there a dynamic env variable I have to replace baseURL with for it to work? I tried researching this with no luck.

See Code below

```
export default {


  saveClient: function(clientData) {
    return axios({
method:"post",
url:"/api/saveClient",
baseURL:"http://localhost:3001",
data:clientData
    })

  }

----------------------
server.js is below



const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors())
// Configure body parser for AJAX requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Serve up static assets
app.use(express.static("client/build"));

var apiRoutes = require("./controllers/clientController.js");
var validatorRoutes = require("./controllers/validatorRoutes.js")
app.use("auth",validatorRoutes)
app.use("/api", apiRoutes);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// Connect to the Mongo DB
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://skillBuilder:qwerty123@ds143707.mlab.com:43707/heroku_2s9vp225",
  {
    useMongoClient: true
  }
);

// Start the API server
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
});
```

---

Comment: Take a look at [Heroku Configuration Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application).

Comment: Config Vars in heroku ?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody wow I was just looking at that and you responded thanks I will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually remove the baseUrl option entirely and use just the relative URL '/api/saveClient'.  This will work for both your dev and production environment. 
 When you use a relative url axios will default to 
http://*your-app-name*.herokuapp.com/api/saveClient.

However, if you had to make the baseUrl explicit, the appropriate baseUrl would be: 
http://*your-app-name*.herokuapp.com.  To avoid hardcoding this you could try something like:

`baseUrl = process.env.baseURL || "http://localhost:3001"`

Heroku lets you set environment variables in an easy fashion in their console at dashboard.heroku.com/apps/*your-app-name*/settings.  I don't think you'll need this, but it's good to know as your app grows and you want to configure your production environment more easily.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jeffrey Kandel , I tried removing the baseURL and it still doesnt work. Wanted to add that I am using React and therefor the routing of pages takes place completely on the front end. So when I am trying to make the api call with the relative URL it is not using the server PORT path etc... My API calls dont work when i manually change the URL like --> http://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/saveClient.

Comment: I think the best way to debug would be to identify a URL that your API is responding to and then working backwards from their.  If I understand correctly, when running locally "http://localhost:3001/api/saveClient" gives you a response, but "http://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/saveClient" doesn't work as intended.  What response do you get when you go to that second URL? (You can check the response status and any message using the Chrome inspector's Network tab)

Comment: Yep you are correct. When I run locally, localhost:3001/api/saveClient" works and its the main reason i added  a specific baseURL because if not it would have done localhost:3000/api/saveClient cause of the React routing. When I try "your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/test" (which I setup to test) I get 'Internal Server Error' 500, and  "your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/saveClient" gives me 404.

Comment: Hmm, this is tough... if you're getting a 500 from /api/test and a 404 from /api/saveClient it sounds like you are hitting the server, but have some api routes set up incorrectly.  I'd look into identifying what URL of the form "your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/..." returns some consistently  successful response.  If you can find that, we can set the axios to the point the right way.  Separately, react router shouldn't alter domain of the site, it should just respond to <Routes> that you've set up in a <Switch> statement.  Can you explain more about localhost:3000 vs :3001?

Comment: It seems like, the way its set up and the way I understand is that once the server fires up and the root / is hit REACT Router takes over and it does seem to be changing the domain somehow. So I changed the port from my server.js to 3000  instead of 3001 to match REACT and my test route works "your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/test". However when I use axios it is giving XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "http://localhost:3001/api/checkClient" in the console. Somehow its still using local host / Any ideas?

Comment: React router doesn't modify the domain. The domain (and this gets a little complicated) is only "localhost:3001" or "your-app-name.herokuapp.com". 
 If you run axios.get('/api/saveClient') your browser will make an XHR request to the current domain + the relative url.  If this is failing it could be a couple things: 1) the domain of the api is different (it's actually your-api-name.herokuapp.com) (this would be a 400 error likely) 2) it's serving it and failing for some reason (more likely a 500 error)

Comment: The error I'm getting is (blocked:mixed-content) so its serving

Comment: Solved it, im so dumb this whole time I wasn't deploying my changes correctly I should have noticed before, thanks for your help and yes all I needed was the relative url

Comment: Happens to us all.  Glad I could help! :-)

Comment: Could you post what you were doing wrong? I'm having the same error, and it's maddening.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by just doing this:

```
exports.homeRoutes = (req, res) => {
  // make request to the /api/users
  //your-app.heroku.com/path/to/your/api
  axios
    .get("https://dashboard.herokuapp.com/api/users")
    .then(function (response) {
      res.render("index", { users: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
};
```

In your case, this hack might work:

```
url:"your-app.herokuapp.com/api/saveClient"
```