# MERN application in Heroku not able to connect to backend

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, middleware

I have created a full stack MERN application and I am trying to deploy it on Heroku. But I can't seem to get the frontend to connect to the backend. I try to do a simple post request to my backend using axios:

```
axios.post("/api/items", { item }).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        this.setState({ sended: true });
      }
    });
```

With this I am also using a proxy from http-proxy-middleware in the setupPorxy.js:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy(['/api' ], { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
}
```

On my server side I have CORS enabled. I have also tried to change `http://localhost:3000` to `https://merninschrijvingen.herokuapp.com`:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
  );
  next();
});
```

I have also defined my client location:

```
app.use("/api/items", items);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server starter on port " + port));
```

This is my axios instance with the BaseUrl:

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.baseURL || "http://localhost:5000/",
});

export default instance;
```

These are the examples of the requests I am sending from the frontend in Heroku:
[image][image]

This is the complete server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

const items = require("./routes/api/items");

const app = express();

//Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://merninschrijvingen.herokuapp.com"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
  );
  next();
});

//DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

//Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

//Use Routes
app.use("/api/items", items);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server starter on port " + port));
```

Comment: Heroku runs your application with a proxy and the PORT is accessible via process.env.PORT. Since you are using express do the following steps. 1)  Enable proxy with *app.enable('trust proxy')*; see [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/happypuppy-server/blob/a1d6313cd8e409b89971a7bc94fef34e696f0901/src/server/Server.ts#L37). 2) Install *cors* (npm install cors --save) and enable it using *app.use(cors())*; see [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/happypuppy-server/blob/a1d6313cd8e409b89971a7bc94fef34e696f0901/src/server/Server.ts#L36).

Comment: 3) Set the correct listening port with *app.listen(process.env.PORT)*; see [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/happypuppy-server/blob/a1d6313cd8e409b89971a7bc94fef34e696f0901/src/server/Server.ts#L75).

Comment: @CarloCorradini It is stilled blocked. I have added app.enable("trust proxy") and app.use(cors()). My app.listen was already correct. I have updated the code in the question above.

Comment: Remove the section where you set the headers. Cors library handle this for you.

Comment: As far as I can see running GET on *https://merninschrijvingen.herokuapp.com/api/items* return a 200 OK response with an empty JSON array, so now is working?

Comment: @CarloCorradini shouldn't I change the `app.use(proxy(["/api"], { target: "http://localhost:5000" }));` inside the setupProxy.js to something like `app.use(proxy(["/api"], { target: "merninschrijvingen.herokuapp.com" }));`

Comment: @CarloCorradini I have also removed the headers. But I still get the error. Because we can do requests to the backend. It seems to me that the frontend isn't making it's request to the right endpoint.

Comment: Remove *app.use(proxy(["/api"], { target: "http://localhost:5000" }));* completely. In addition try to check the heroku logs. Secondly what's the error you are receiving from the frontend?

Comment: Show an example of the request you are making from the frontend to the backend, so I can understand it better. Thanks

Comment: @CarloCorradini I have added pictures of the requests and the axios instance I use to connect to the backend.

Comment: See [Axios Api calls in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164330/axios-api-calls-in-heroku). Axios request logs? They generate 404 or ?

Comment: @CarloCorradini I removed `baseURL: process.env.baseURL || "http://localhost:5000/"` from my axios instance and this fixed the problem!

Comment: Great! Have a nice coding day :)